# mojofailureException in Graphhopper

Tags: java, bash, maven, intellij-idea, graphhopper

I am new to such complex solutions and some environments.
I am trying to get a control over Graphhopper solution.
I have cloned it from GIT, and tried to compile and run it from bash with

```
$ ./graphhopper.sh web slovenia-latest.osm.pbf

## using java 1.8.0_161 (64bit) from
## using existing osm file slovenia-latest.osm.pbf
## building graphhopper jar: tools/target/graphhopper-tools-0.10-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
## using maven at C:\Martin\WS5\Graphhopper\graphhopper\maven
## compilation of parent failed
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The project com.graphhopper:graphhopper-parent:pom:0.10-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] GraphHopper Parent Project
[INFO] GraphHopper Core
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader for OpenStreetMap Data
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader JSON
[INFO] GraphHopper Tools
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GraphHopper Parent Project 0.10-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GraphHopper Core 0.10-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ graphhopper-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 48 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ graphhopper-core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 288 source files to C:\Martin\WS5\Graphhopper\graphhopper2\core\target\classes
[WARNING] Unable to autodetect 'javac' path, using 'javac' from the environment.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] GraphHopper Parent Project ......................... SUCCESS [  0.160 s]
[INFO] GraphHopper Core ................................... FAILURE [  4.929 s]
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader for OpenStreetMap Data .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader JSON ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Tools .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.339 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-11T18:36:38+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project graphhopper-core: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :graphhopper-core
```

It seems that the "core" is not compiled due to MojoFailureException, but I have no idea how to fix it.

On the other hand, I can open the project with IntelliJ, and try to run graphhopper.sh from there, I get

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Martin\WS5\Graphhopper\graphhopper2 "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=59256:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.3.4
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] GraphHopper Parent Project
[INFO] GraphHopper Core
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader for OpenStreetMap Data
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader for Gtfs Data
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader JSON
[INFO] GraphHopper Tools
[INFO] GraphHopper Directions API hand-crafted Java Client.
[INFO] GraphHopper Web
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader for Shapefile Data
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] GraphHopper Parent Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Core ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader for OpenStreetMap Data .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader for Gtfs Data ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader JSON ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Tools .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Directions API hand-crafted Java Client. SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Web .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GraphHopper Reader for Shapefile Data .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.270 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-11T19:06:34+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

I also don't know where and which goals should I set... :/

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you have the JDK installed? The JRE is not sufficient.

Comment: Or use the quick start for users: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/web/quickstart.md